# How to put HTML code between add_settings_field in custom Wordpress theme options page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display a horizontal rule between two specific fields.
If I write the following code, the `<hr/>` appears on the top of the screen. How can I display it in the desired position? I don't want to put the HTML code in the callback function.

Is there any other way to achieve this? Thank you!

```
<?php
// ...
add_settings_field(
    'telephone',
    'Telephone',
    'my_theme_textbox_callback',
    'my_theme_contact_option',
    'my_theme_contact',
    array(
        'context'=>'my_theme_contact_option',
        'name'=>'telephone',
    )
);

add_settings_field(
    'fax',
    'Fax',
    'my_theme_textbox_callback',
    'my_theme_contact_option',
    'my_theme_contact',
    array(
        'context'=>'my_theme_contact_option',
        'name'=>'fax',
    )
);

echo '<br/>'; // <---- THIS DOESN'T DISPLAY IN THE RIGHT POSITION

add_settings_field(
    'address',
    'Address',
    'my_theme_textbox_callback',
    'my_theme_contact_option',
    'my_theme_contact',
    array(
        'context'=>'my_theme_contact_option',
        'name'=>'address',
    )
);
// ...
?>
```

Comment: the reason it isnt displaying is because those are php functions, not what is actually displayed. You need to locate the place where the html is being generated.

Comment: ~If the line appears at the top of the page, it suggests that wherever this section is in the code, it is being echo'd lower down the page

Comment: I understand this, fields are printed all together in the two functions `settings_fields( 'my_theme_contact_option' ); do_settings_sections( 'my_theme_contact_option' );` so probably this can't be done with echo. If there is no other alternative, one option is to put the string as an argument in the callback function. But this doesn't give much freedom to customize the appearence.

Comment: What about modifying the function to print the break?